# Android MediaCodec and GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, glsurfaceview

I'm trying to playback a video using MediaCodec and renders it via a GLSurfaceView so that I can have a frame callback.

```
package com.alwaysinnovating.aimediacodec;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaCodec.BufferInfo;
import android.media.MediaExtractor;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.opengl.EGLConfig;
import android.opengl.GLES11Ext;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;

class PlayBackSurface extends GLSurfaceView {
    public MainRenderer mRenderer;

    public PlayBackSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mRenderer = new MainRenderer(context, this);
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }
}

class MainRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer, SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener {
    private int[] hTex;
    private SurfaceTexture mSTexture;
    private boolean mUpdateST = false;
    private PlayerThread mPlayer = null;
    private GLSurfaceView mGLSV;

    MainRenderer(Context c, GLSurfaceView s) {
        mGLSV = s;
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mUpdateST) {
                mSTexture.updateTexImage();
                mUpdateST = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void doPrepare() {
        mUpdateST = false;

        if (mSTexture != null) {
            mSTexture.release();
            mSTexture = null;
        }

        if (hTex != null)
            GLES20.glDeleteTextures(1, hTex, 0);
        hTex = null;

        hTex = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, hTex, 0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, hTex[0]);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        mSTexture = new SurfaceTexture(hTex[0]);
        mSTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);

        Surface s = new Surface(mSTexture);
        mPlayer = new PlayerThread(s);
        mPlayer.start();
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        doPrepare();
    }

    public synchronized void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture st) {
        mUpdateST = true;
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 arg0, javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig arg1) {
    }
}

class PlayerThread extends Thread {
    private static final String SAMPLE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/local-25fps.mp4";
    private MediaExtractor extractor;
    private MediaCodec decoder;
    private Surface surface;

    public PlayerThread(Surface surface) {
        this.surface = surface;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        extractor = new MediaExtractor();
        try {
            extractor.setDataSource(SAMPLE);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < extractor.getTrackCount(); i++) {
            MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i);
            String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
            if (mime.startsWith("video/")) {
                extractor.selectTrack(i);
                decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
                decoder.configure(format, surface, null, 0);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (decoder == null) {
            Log.e("DecodeActivity", "Can't find video info!");
            return;
        }

        decoder.start();

        ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
        ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
        BufferInfo info = new BufferInfo();
        boolean isEOS = false;
        long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            if (!isEOS) {
                int inIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(10000);
                if (inIndex >= 0) {
                    ByteBuffer buffer = inputBuffers[inIndex];
                    int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(buffer, 0);
                    if (sampleSize < 0) {
                        // We shouldn't stop the playback at this point, just pass the EOS
                        // flag to decoder, we will get it again from the
                        // dequeueOutputBuffer
                        Log.d("DecodeActivity", "InputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
                        decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                        isEOS = true;
                    } else {
                        decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, sampleSize, extractor.getSampleTime(), 0);
                        extractor.advance();
                    }
                }
            }

            int outIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 10000);
            switch (outIndex) {
            case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
                Log.d("DecodeActivity", "INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED");
                outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
                break;
            case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
                Log.d("DecodeActivity", "New format " + decoder.getOutputFormat());
                break;
            case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
                Log.d("DecodeActivity", "dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!");
                break;
            default:
                ByteBuffer buffer = outputBuffers[outIndex];
                Log.v("DecodeActivity", "We can't use this buffer but render it due to the API limit, " + buffer);

                // We use a very simple clock to keep the video FPS, or the video
                // playback will be too fast
                while (info.presentationTimeUs / 1000 > System.currentTimeMillis() - startMs) {
                    try {
                        sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, true);
                break;
            }

            // All decoded frames have been rendered, we can stop playing now
            if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                Log.d("DecodeActivity", "OutputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
                break;
            }
        }

        decoder.stop();
        decoder.release();
        extractor.release();
    }
}
```

The screen is black. as I do:

```
        Surface s = new Surface(mSTexture);
        mPlayer = new PlayerThread(s);
```

The frame is rendered into a surface that goes nowhere. What am I doing wrong or how can I link this Surface and my GLSurfaceView?

Comment: Nothing is being rendered because your `onDrawFrame()` method doesn't render anything. See Grafika for some examples (https://github.com/google/grafika).

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting code indeed but it's doesn't completely answer my question. He uses TextureView which doesn't have a frame draw callback. I should perhaps reformulate my question to: should I copy the content of mSTexture to my SurfaceView and how can I do that?

Comment: SurfaceTexture converts an incoming frame of graphics (from MediaCodec, the Camera, OpenGL ES rendering, Canvas rendering, etc) to an OpenGL ES "external" texture. You can render that texture onto the GLSurfaceView with GLES rendering commands. (You could also just pass the SurfaceView's Surface to MediaCodec and skip the intermediate step, in which case SurfaceView makes more sense than GLSurfaceView, but that only makes sense if you have no interest in modifying the video frames.) See the two "play video" Activities in Grafika -- there's one for SurfaceView, one for TextureView.

Comment: You're the one who wrote Grafika! I didn't know it was you. Beautiful code :-) Arghh, I only read and tested PlayMovieActivity.java while I guess I should have investigated PlayMovieSurfaceActivity.java... I'm going to take a look at this... Thanks. You can convert your comment into an answer and I will mark it as green.

Comment: Well, SurfaceView like you said won't allow me to intercept the frame, which I want to do. I still think that I have the right approach. In the OnDraw, I need to copy mSTexture to the GLSurface using GL apis. How do I do that?

Comment: You haven't said what it is you're trying to accomplish, but I'd guess that either the "texture from camera" Activity or the "camera capture" Activity in Grafika is close to what you need. Replace Camera with MediaCodec. Grafika favors SurfaceView over GLSurfaceView because the latter gets in the way sometimes (it's just a bunch of helper classes wrapped around the former); CameraCaptureActivity uses GLSurfaceView just to prove that it can.

Answer (score 0):

PS: I'm writing this off the top of my head, so I might get some method names wrong.

You need to register the onFrameAvailable callback on your surface texture. Inside the callback, do not call st.updateTexImage since the method needs to be called on the OpenGL es thread.

Call the GLSurfaceView.requestRender and your onDrawFrame method will get called. In there, you can update your surface texture image, bind to the texture and do whatever you want with it.

Oh, you'll also have to change your render mode to WHEN_DIRTY or something like that.